# How do I reference a Subform with a Variable?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to reference a subform's properties by a variable so that I can loop through different subform names.  Through much google-fu I think i'm close but it keeps saying it can't find the field "Controls".

```
  f = "[TerritoryCode] = """ & tcode & """"
  strsubform = "subDM" & loopnumber
  Me!Controls(strsubform).Form.Filter = f
  Me!Controls(strsubform).Form.FilterOn = True
```

So strsubform should keep producing something like "subDM1", "subDM2", etc, and then it's going to filter via the variable f.  This works just fine if I directly reference subDM1, but that's no fun.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `Me.Controls` instead of `Me!Controls` and see if that works any better.

Comment: Dude!  Put that as an answer and I'll check you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case "Bang notation" (`foo!thing`) refers to the value of a *Field* in the Form (i.e., the Recordset of the Form), while "dot notation" (`foo.thing`) always refers to Properties, Methods, and Collections belonging to an object. So,

```
Me!Controls
```

equates to

```
Me.Fields("Controls").Value
```

but `Controls` is a `Collection` of `Control` objects, not a field name. Therefore we need to use

```
Me.Controls
```